# List.Add() not working in c# - getter and setter issue?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got this property:

```
public virtual List<FieldImage> Images { get; set; }
```

If i go and get the class that has this property, from my database using entity like so...

```
Field field = this.unitOfWork.FieldRepository.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(fieldID));
```

and then add an image to the array:

```
FieldImage fieldImage = new FieldImage()
{
    CreatedAt = dateNow,
    UpdatedAt = dateNow,
    CreatedBy = unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetByID(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
    File = file,
    Field = field
};

field.Images.Add(fieldImage);
```

and then save the context like so:

```
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

All is okay. The images array gets filled up, and the save to database works great.

If i change the property to this:

```
private List<FieldImage> _images;
public virtual List<FieldImage> Images
{
    get
    {
        return 
            this._images != null ? 
            this._images.Where(x => x.DeletedAt == null).ToList() : 
            new List<FieldImage>();
    }
    set
    {
        this._images = value;
    }
}
```

And now do the exact thing i was dong before, the field.Images remains empty but no error is made... and ofcourse the database save doesn't occur.

What am i doing wrong?

**Edit:**

This works, thanks... Looks like i had issue with my if logic:

```
    private List<FieldImage> _images;
    public virtual List<FieldImage> Images
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._images == null)
            {
                this._images = new List<FieldImage>();
            }

            return this._images;
        }
        set
        {
            this._images = value.Where( x => x.DeletedAt == null ).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In regards to the edit, that will fix this problem, but it ought to delete all of the entries where deleted at is set.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean, and would LOVE to understand.. but in terms of answering the question... You win. Thanks bro... the above is working well.

Comment: Oh sugar it's still not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getter is *always returning a new list*.  When you call

```
field.Images.Add(fieldImage);
```

You are getting a newly created list and adding an item to it, but there's *no connection to the source data*.

Some options:

- Add an `Add` method that adds the item to the *original* list
- Filter the items when the data is loaded instead of when it' fetched
- When asking for the property, set the field value (`_images`) to the filtered list

Comment: But my code says, if not null... then go and return what's in the array already... otherwise create a new List and return that? I'm confused <doiiii>

Comment: No, your code is returning a _new_ list that's a filtered _copy_ of the original.  There's no tie back to the source list.

Comment: Do you recommend Robert Conte Rositos answer then?

Comment: No - it does the same thing, but returns it as an `IEnumerable` so you _can't add to it_.  I have added some options to my answer.

Comment: That's one option - however you could still add a deleted image and it would be returned by the getter.  I would think about _when_ you want to filter out deleted images and if/how you would prevent them from getting added.

Answer (score 3):

Why you are doing this kind of operation on your model?
You can add another column flagged as "NotMapped" to do the same operation, please read this code:

```
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<FieldImage> NotDeletedImages 
{
    get 
    {
        return this.Images.Where(x => !x.Deleted);
    }
}
```

I suppose you apply this filter because you want to "display" different data. In this case why you don't use a view model?

Comment: I used this in the end, the other one was so touchy and not worth the hassle!